# cannot print dynamic message using es6, babel, webpack 3, javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, webpack-2

I am trying to print dynamic message using webpack 3 and ES6 using babel and `hotmodulereplacement()` in webpack but, I cannot print messages. Below is the code. 
cannot print:

```
var newMessage = () => ('<p>${messages.hi} ${messages.event}</p>');
```

messages.js file

```
module.exports = {
    hi: 'Hello there  content changed',
    event: 'this is new webpack'
};
```

index.js file

```
var messages = require('./messages');
var newMessage = () => ('<p>${messages.hi} ${messages.event}</p>');
var app = document.getElementById('app');
app.innerHTML = newMessage();

if(module.hot){
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="app"></div>
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output on webpage:

> ${messages.hi} ${messages.event}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backticks ( ` ) instead of quotes (').

```
`<p>${messages.hi} ${messages.event}</p>`
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to use the new template literals:
for that you have to enclose the string in backticks

```
`<p>${messages.hi} ${messages.event}</p>`
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals